# fowLayoutPanel Custom Vertical Scrolling

Tags: c#, visual-studio, flowlayoutpanel, vertical-scroll

I have a `flowLayoutPanel` with several `User Controls` in it as shown in the image below:
[image]

The First `User Control` is the header in `flowLayoutPanel` with description about the `User Controls` below it, Now when `User Controls` populate the `flowLayoutPanel` and vertical scroll bar appears, then when I scroll down `flowLayoutPanel` then first 'User Control'(Header which contain details) also scroll down and details are not shown to user, I want the vertical scrolling to start from second `User Control` so that my Header will visible to user all time.

Comment: FlowLayoutPanel has no such feature.  You'll have to put the "header control" above the panel.  Or use the kind of control that was made for this, like ListView or DataGridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FlowLayoutPanel has no such function for now, but you can create a new FlowLayoutPanel as Header.
As follows:

[image]

Or use dategridview directly, its Header is suspended by default, as shown below

[image]

Comment: Yes you are right, I have to use one more `flowLayoutPanel`

Comment: wenbingeng-MSFT can you guide me how you capture and add screen video in answer, So in future I can add it to my questions

Comment: @AdilAhmed I'm using a software called ScreenToGif that takes a screenshot of my computer screen and generates a GIF. Just drag and drop the gif directly into your question to achieve the effect you want.